# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: php, sockets, azure

For two days yet I trying to resolve this problem

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

My hosting is Azure and he has very bad interface. Programming language is PHP, I have database in same resource group with domain, account data is correct. what I do incorrect?

line with problem

```
mysqli_connect($SERVER, $USER, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE);
```

Comment: Does the user you're using to connect have the required permissions?

Comment: As bcdf0225312fef - it username I get from clearDB panel

Comment: Make sure that you add the user to the database as well.

Comment: What are you using for `$SERVER`? `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your connection string in a Web App with MySQL on CLearDB:

1. select your service in Azure Portal
2. click Settings
3. select Application Settings and scroll down to Connection String and click in "Show connection string values"
4. copy the middle column of the table you will get something like:

   Database=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;Data Source=YOUR_HOSTNAME;User Id=YOUR_USERNAME;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD

That's it, copy and replace in your code!

**Protip**: you can ping YOUR_HOSTNAME and use the IP instead the HOSTNAME to improve speed ;)