# PDO statement in Azure websites with MySQL in-App

Tags: php, mysql, azure, pdo, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web app to communicate with MySQL In-App for Azure website.
However I'm getting error as,

"Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."

I have made sure that host, database, username and password are correct.
Don't know the issue, looks like authentication issue though.

Sample Code :

```
$pdocon = "mysql:host".$conStr["Data Source"].";dbname=".$conStr["Database"];
try {
    $conn = new PDO($pdocon, $conStr["User ID"], $conStr["Password"]);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Where, if I simply print `$pdocon` I have values.
Also, I have correct values in my `$conStr` array.

Comment: What are you using for the host name in the connection?

Comment: it requires host name, where in my case it is always "127.0.0.1:someport"

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778608/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-2002-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket help?

Comment: Also check that your using the right port number.

Comment: @NigelRen Nope, as it is more of MySQL on ClearDB, and my port number is right, I just checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lower App Service Plan, you may scale to a higher App Service Plan and then check.

Check in your web app application settings if there is a connection string. PHPmyadmin uses MYSQLCONNSTR_ to connect to the MySQL server. If you have a connection string in application setting change the connection string type to Custom , so you can still have the information if needed or delete it.  This will force PHPmyadmin to access MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb and connect to the MySQL in-app server.

Reference:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/09/08/troubleshooting-faq-for-mysql-in-apppreview/

As mentioned in this document (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), Connection attempts to local addresses (e.g. localhost, 127.0.0.1) and the machine's own IP will fail, except if another process in the same sandbox has created a listening socket on the destination port.
Rejected connection attempts, such as the following example which attempts to connect to 127.0.0.1:80, will result an exception error.

Refer these FAQs (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/MySQL-in-app) for more details:

Where can I find MySql Credentials (connection string)?
The connection string flows to your application as an env variable MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb. Beware that we are not using the default MySql port (3306). In fact, the port number may vary for each application life cycle depending on its availability at startup time. The port info is also available as an env variable WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT to your site.

How to use phpMyAdmin with MySql in-app?
phpMyAdmin is enabled by default with the feature. You can access it thru https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpMyAdmin/. Since MySql is only started with the main site, do make sure that the main site is running (simplest way is to turn on AlwaysOn) before using phpMyAdmin. Unlike phpMyAdmin from SiteExtenions gallery, this phpMyAdmin is aware of MySql credentials and will connect automatically.
Important: If you previously have phpMyAdmin installed via SiteExtension gallery, you will have to uninstall it. Since this phpMyAdmin from SiteExtension gallery will take precedent and it is notMySql In-App aware, it will not work with MySql In-App.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the values for connection string are not correct. That message is related to a bad username, password, database or server values.

Try to check [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2017/05/04/azure-app-service-how-to-read-parse-connection-strings-via-php/) if you are obtaining the connection values in another form. The connection string is stored under D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt

Another option can be related to stopped MySQL process -only for free app service plan- in such case you should run any PHP file that fires the MySQL process.